# Log heap samples on garbage collection for the hp2ps tool

Tags: node.js, v8

### P.S:

**According to [this link](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/v8-users/3JEoQD5kOIk/BQX6WRJuB7gJ) log_gc does not work anymore on latest node(v8)**

---

`Node.js` has this following option `v8-option`:

```
  --log_gc (Log heap samples on garbage collection for the hp2ps tool)
```

I tried to run it, but now I would like to know how use(view) this data? what is hp2ps? I did a google search and found some sort of haskell tool?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This generates a PostScript file. This postscript file is then viewable with the [hp2ps](http://www.macs.hw.ac.uk/~dsg/gph/docs/4.06/users_guide/hp2ps.html) tool, indeed written in Haskell. It allows you to view graphs related to the memory.

[PostScript](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PostScript) is a language that allows you to render documents similar to PDF.

Comment: I do not get a postscript file, but only a v8.log file when using node --log --log_gc <file>

Comment: oops I get a postscript file from the heap data, but I do not know how??

Comment: What do you mean, you don't know how?

Comment: Oops that comment made no sense at all. I need to get postscript file from heap data(v8.log?), but I do not know how.